# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'strides'

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

The Nvidia model is showing error for strides, even if I initialize them to the default value of  (1,1)
I am using 'strides' as a replacement for the 'subsample' argument in previous versions of keras can someone explain the new syntax of using them.

```
def nvidia_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(24,5,5, strides = (2,2), input_shape= (66,200,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(36,5,5, strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(48,5,5, strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64,3,3, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64,3,3, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))                                               #50% nodes turned to zero

  model.add( Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(100, activation ='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Dense(50, activation ='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation ='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  
  optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-3)
  model.compile(loss = 'mse' , optimizer = optimizer)
  return model

model = nvidia_model()
print(model.summary)
```

```
Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-aff2a2709b79> in <module>()
----> 1 model = nvidia_model()
      2 print(model.summary)

<ipython-input-82-7942ade664af> in nvidia_model()
      1 def nvidia_model():
      2   model = Sequential()
----> 3   model.add(Conv2D(24,5,5, strides = (2,2), input_shape= (66,200,3), activation='relu'))
      4   model.add(Conv2D(36,5,5, strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
      5   model.add(Conv2D(48,5,5, strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'strides'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never worked with `tensorflow`, but according to the documentation of [`Conv2D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) it's defined as

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None,
    dilation_rate=(1, 1), groups=1, activation=None, use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros',
    kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs
)
```

As you can see `strides` is the third parameter.

Now you use `Conv2D(24,5,5, strides = (2,2), input_shape= (66,200,3), activation='relu')` where the third parameter is `5` and then you try to set `strides` again with the keyword parameter. It seems there is one parameter too much in your call.

Imagine the little Python gnome handling your code: "OK, the boss wants an instance of `Conv2D`. He sets the first argument `filters` to `4`, the second argument `kernel_size` to `2` and the third argument `strides`to `2`. Done with the positional arguments. Now let's continue with the keyword arguments. Here we have `strides` and ... oh, I already have `strides`, so I don't know what to do. The boss might be angry so I'll tell him exactly what happenend: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'strides'`"

Comment: Now i feel like an idiot cause that worked by putting kernel size in brackets lol. thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

```
model.add(Conv2D(24,5,5, strides = (2,2), input_shape= (66,200,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(36,5,5, strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(48,5,5, strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
```

For these lines use parentheses like the following example

```
model.add(Conv2D(24,(5,5), strides = (2,2), input_shape= (66,200,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(36,(5,5), strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(48,(5,5), strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu'))
```